# How can I change windows scaling for different display resolution? (and rotation problem!!)

Tags: display, resolution

I really enjoy ElementaryOS and I want it to be my everyday operating system, but I have some issues...

I'm currently running 3 monitors: one 4K, and two more displays (lower resolution) in vertical position next to my 4K. So, I need to **change the windows scaling** of my 4K monitor because all the things are too small, and **rotate** my 2 external displays.

I tried, but, I think that the **Display Settings** are broken: I cannot apply the rotation - I can only change resolution and then click *apply*, with bugs of x,y,z positioning and more problems...
I updated and upgraded everything but I can't fix the rotation problems.

**How can I rotate my vertical displays and fix the windows scaling properties of the "big one"?**

Thank you for your help

---

**UP:** I finally made it. I rotated both the screen. But I still can't move them. That's what it should look like (but I can't click on *"Apply"*):

[image: That's what it should look like (but I can't click on *"Apply"*)]

[image: And... what it's now.]

And... what it's now.

Answer (score 0):

Which release are you running?

Loki will automatically detect and set the native resolution of each screen.  Then, the Display applet in Settings will have a context menu to rotate your secondary displays.

You can change the font size under Accessibility.  If you want to change the interface scaling, use dconf editor under org.gnome.desktop.interface.scaling-factor.  I find however that 0 (let the system autodetect) works the best.

On my development workstation I have a 4k and two 1080 displays.  The 4k and one 1080 are in landscape, while the third display is in portrait orientation.  The Display applet under settings properly rotates the portrait screen, and the layout saves and restores flawlessly.  I use "Largest" font size in Accessibility, and then per application I will zoom in or out if I am running it on the 4k or a 1080 display.

Each screen cannot have its own scaling or font sizes.  These settings are system wide.  Therefore find a suitable middle ground that looks ok on all the displays, and stick with it.  This is a known limitation of all current Linux window managers, from my experience.

Comment: I'm running Loki 0.4.1 Loki.
No window scaling :( okkey.

Yes, it sets the native resolution of each screen and it saves the settings but I cannot rotate the screen... I can't set them in portrait, it doesn't work. I can apply _900p_ insted of _1440p_ but when I select _"Clockwise"_ the _"Apply"_ button become grey. The same thing happen when I try to move the position.

Comment: I temporarily disable the two displays... and now they doesn't show up properly. I can turn them on but then I lose the first and second screen (with all my programs opened, and obviously the notification _"keep current settings"_. I can see only a beautiful background... empty, on the last screen (the others with _no segnal_). How can I reset all the monitor settings? If I hard-reset it restore the one screen view only. Thanks for your help.